# Prove that there is always a perfect match

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

Let G<sub>n</sub> be a graph with 2n nodes: a<sub>0</sub>, a<sub>1</sub>, ..., a<sub>n-1</sub>, b<sub>0</sub>, b<sub>1</sub>, ..., b<sub>n-1</sub>. Let the edges be formed like this:

> Node $a_i$ connects with $b_j$ and $b_k$,
>   where $j = 2i \pmod n$ and $k = (2i + 1) \pmod n$

Prove that every G<sub>n</sub> *has a perfect match*.

---

For n = 4, we would get this:

[image]

where the perfect match would be (a<sub>0</sub>, b<sub>0</sub>), (a<sub>1</sub>, b<sub>2</sub>), (a<sub>2</sub>, b<sub>1</sub>) and (a<sub>3</sub>, b<sub>3</sub>).

---

My attempt:

I wrote some code which performs a greedy algorithm to find a match and for G<sub>4</sub> and G<sub>5</sub> I see that the output is a perfect match. However, I am not sure how to prove that in math (that there is a perfect match (not necessarily found with the greedy algorithm)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that for each $i=0,1,\ldots,n-1$, $a_i$ is joined to $b_{2i}$ and $b_{2i+1}$, where the subscripts are taken modulo $n$.  This means the degree of vertex $a_i$ is 2 for each $i$.

The degree of vertex $b_i$ is also 2 for each $i$.  One way to prove this is to consider the case of even $n$ and odd $n$ separately.  Observe that the neighbors of $a_0$ are the first two vertices on the right side, the neighbors of $a_1$ are the next two vertices on the right side, and so on. If $n$ is even, then the vertices $b_{2i}$ and $b_{2i+1}$ have the same set of neighbors, namely $a_i$ and $a_{i+n/2}$. If $n$ is odd, then the argument is only slightly more complicated - some vertex will have the last vertex $b_{n-1}$ and the first vertex $b_0$ as a neighbor.

So the bipartite graph is 2-regular.  By Hall's theorem, the graph has a perfect matching.

Answer (score 2):

I think one can prove this by Hall's marriage theorem. Now all we have to show is that for any $X \subset A$, $\mid N(X) \mid \geq \mid X \mid $. where $A=$ {$a_0,a_1,a_2 \dots a_{n-1}$}. I feel that this should be clear as well, because any vertex $a_i$ is connected to two vertex $b_j$ and $b_{j+1}$ for some $j<n$.

From here I think we can do a proof by contradiction. If $\mid N(X) \mid \geq \mid X \mid $ is not true for some $X \subset A$ there must exist $a_i,a_r\in A$ with the same neighbors. This should imply $i=r$.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but I do not remember what `N(X)` denotes, can you please explain?

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned that, $N(x)$ is the set of all neighbors of vertices in X.

Comment: I am not sure I follow your proof, it is based on the fact that a node of the a type will have two vertices connected to it of b type, but that shouldn't be enough, I mean what if all the a nodes are connected to only two b nodes? Maybe the `i = j` part confuses me too!

Comment: What I meant was $i=r$, I made a mistake there. Also The case that you mentioned will not happen, No two vertices in A will have the same neighbors.

Answer (score 1):

When $n$ is odd, for $0\leqslant i\leqslant  \frac{n-3}{2}$, $a_i$ is connected to $b_{2i}$ and $b_{2i+1}$. For $\frac{n+1}{2}\leqslant i\leqslant  n-1$, $a_i$ is connected to $b_{2i-n}$ and $b_{2i+1-n}$. Also, $a_{\frac{n-1}{2}}$ is connected to $b_{n-1}$ and $b_0$. Now, $(a_i,b_{2i})$ for $0\leqslant i\leqslant  \frac{n-3}{2}$, $(a_j, b_{2j-n})$ for $\frac{n+1}{2}\leqslant j\leqslant  n-1$, and $(a_{\frac{n-1}{2}},b_{n-1})$ is a perfect matching. (i.e. $(a_0, b_0)(a_1,b_2)\dots (a_{\frac{n-1}{2}},b_{n-1})(a_{\frac{n+1}{2}},b_{1})(a_{\frac{n+3}{2}},b_{3})\dots (a_{n-1},b_{n-2})$.)

When $n$ is even, for $0\leqslant i\leqslant  \frac{n}{2}-1$, $a_i$ is connected to $b_{2i}$ and $b_{2i+1}$. For $\frac{n}{2}\leqslant i\leqslant  n-1$, $a_i$ is connected to $b_{2i-n}$ and $b_{2i+1-n}$. Now, $(a_i,b_{2i})$ for $0\leqslant i\leqslant  \frac{n}{2}-1$, and $(a_j, b_{2j-n})$ for $\frac{n}{2}\leqslant j\leqslant  n-1$ is a perfect matching. (i.e. $(a_0, b_0)(a_1,b_2)\dots (a_{\frac{n}{2}-1},b_{n-2})(a_{\frac{n}{2}},b_{1})(a_{\frac{n}{2}+1},b_{3})\dots (a_{n-1},b_{n-1})$.)

Comment: How did you compute the numbers (assume whichever you want for `n`), especially the factors is what bugs me.

Comment: We just need to check when $2i$ or $2i+1$ is greater than $n-1$, then we need to subtract it by $n$ to get the congruence.

Comment: That makes sense, but it's still unclear to me how yo got `n-3/2` there (for example), sorry for asking again, I just want to be sure that I am getting what you answered. :)

Comment: Sure. Since $2\cdot\frac{n-3}{2}+1=n-2<n-1$, but for the next term $\frac{n-1}{2}$, we have $2\cdot\frac{n-1}{2}+1=n>n-1$.